# Accessing buttons which are in ResourceDictionary from codebehind

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary

I have a WPF project with a folder Themes in which there is a Generic.xaml file which looks like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ikea.Master">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Style/Master.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Master}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Master}">
            <StackPanel>

                        <StackPanel Margin="10" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Button Style="{StaticResource RoundCorner}" Name="btn1"  Command="NavigationCommands.GoToPage" CommandParameter="ViewModel/Back.xaml" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=frmContent}" ></Button>
                            <Button Style="{StaticResource RoundCorner}" Name="btn2" Command="NavigationCommands.GoToPage" CommandParameter="ViewModel/Home.xaml" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=frmContent}" ></Button>
                            <Button Style="{StaticResource RoundCorner}" Name="btn3" Command="NavigationCommands.GoToPage" CommandParameter="ViewModel/Help.xaml" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=frmContent}" ></Button>

            </StackPanel >

            </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In the Master.xaml file I define a style for RoundCorner.

Now, what I want to do is change the content of the buttons via code behind of the Back.xaml, Home.xaml, etc. These buttons appear on all of my pages. How can I access btn1, btn2, btn3 from code behind?

Application.Current.Resources gives me nothing.

Comment: Better to change content via Binding, not directly in xaml.cs

Comment: @Firoz I removed the Content property from the buttons. I want to change their content but how do I do that? I can't access them from code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use VisualTreeHelper class if your elements already rendered.
Here is some rough method that is supposed to find buttons for you, if it help - redesign it for your needs

```
    public static IEnumerable<Button> FindButtons(DependencyObject container, string name)
    {
        if (container == null)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(container); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(container, i);
            var button = child as Button;

            if (button != null && button.Name == name)
            {
                yield return button;
            }

            foreach (var childOfChild in FindButtons(child, name))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
```

You are supposed to get a bunch of buttons that fits specified name.

Comment: And what would be the container in this case?

Comment: any container on any level that contains those buttons. in general it may be Window, but as close to buttons container you pass as a parameter the less time it would take to get buttons